# How to create a link with Document ID to show PDF file

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am trying to show the PDF file of a link but when I try to pass the document Id I get the following error
Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

```
documents = [SELECT Id, Name
                                    from Document
                                    WHERE Document.folderid = '00lG0000001bBXb'
                                    ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC Limit 5];

public string pdfView {get;set}
         for (documents doc : documents){
          pdfView = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+ doc.Id+'&headerHeight=null&footerHeight=null#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90' ;
          }
```

Visualforce page

```
<h2>DOCUMENTS</h2>
                <ul>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!documents}" var="document" id="recentDocsRepeat">
                        <li>
                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!pdfView}" id="docListItem">{!document.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                        </li>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed 
I was using documents instead of the type of Documents

```
for (Document doc : documents){
              pdfView = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+ doc.Id+'&headerHeight=null&footerHeight=null#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90' ;
              }
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation about why that fixed the issue?

Comment: sure @AdrianLarson I just added